# Arithmetic Division For Two Table In SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do a very simple division in SQL (PostgreSQL). I want to get the count of all the record from two tables, and divide them and output to another table.

For example, we have two tables, `table1` and `table2`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table2;
```

Now the above queries will be both one column one row, which is the count of the table1 and table2.

I would like to get the two number divide (`COUNT(TABLE1)/COUNT(TABLE2)`), how should I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2);
```

This does integer division.  If you want a real number:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)::numeric / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2);
```